# Affinity Designer: Change colour of textured image brush

Tags: png, brush, affinity-designer

I created a brush from a textured image. However, I can't change the colour. Is this even possible to do on Affinity Designer? If so, how?

I created the brush in a transparent background. Then I saved it as a .png. Finally, I imported it as a textured image brush.

Here are some images showing how its colour does not change as expected...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not insert fill color, change the color of the stroke. It unfortunately will have the same brightness level as the original brush definition image had, so black is not recolorable. That's of course for keeping textures.

To make some coloring possible the original base shape is often 50% grey. Stroke color =black leaves it grey.

But you can insert layer effect Color Overlay.It changes also black. Colorize with it.

Color Overlay (surprisingly) doesn't neutralize Bevel&Emboss effect in case you use it for some easy-to-make glosses, so at least something works better than expected. Actually A.D. has numerous such details.

Be sure there's no transparency in the original base image shape area if you do not want transparent strokes.

**ADD:** Custom vector brushes are based on bitmap images. They can originally be vector shapes which are exported as PNG, the selected shape only, no background!. Only hue and saturation are selectable when you change the stroke color of a painted shape. Applying effect "Color Overlay" is as easy as changing the stroke color. Try it and see. It doesn't affect the brush, only to the shape which is painted.gets the new color.

Apply effect Color Overlay to a group if you want to colorize a bunch of shapes at the same time:

[image]

If it happens that you have lost your Effects panel apply View > Studio > Reset Studio.

Comment: How would you create your brushes s you can change their colours in an easier manner?

Comment: @Joehat there's more in the answer. Effect Color Overlay to the painted shape is the easiest way, brushes are not colorizable in any effective way.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been down this rabbit hole: there are two distinct methods of adding brushes a) New Textured Intensity Brush and b) New Textured Image Brush.

If you're exporting PNG and importing as b) an Image brush you get the behaviour described above.

If you create an a) Textures Intensity Brush, then you can select the stroke colour using the colour wheel/swatches etc and the stroke will take on that colour.

The only gotcha is that you need to export the brush in grayscale. Black is 100% transparent and white is 100% opaque and takes on the colour.

here's the first result I found showing the technique on YouTube for those who prefer seeing to comprehend: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfS9uHC-6Gs&t=369s